# Replay of pcap file from local ip to public ip

Tags: python, scapy

I am replaying packets from pcap file using scapy from local machine to public. The pcap file contains different packets with multiple protocols like, llmnr, dhcp, http, udp, tcp, nbns e.t.c. The public ip is my VM(Virtual Machine) on azure. When I send packets to public ip, I only get few packets. Most of them are lost and I also get Malformed traffic, not the original packet there. Is there any way in scapy  by using that I can receive all packets there.

The python script:

```
pca = rdpcap("Eg.pcap")
for pkt in pca:
    if TCP in pkt:
        npkt = (IP(dst="Public IP")/TCP()/Raw(pkt.payload))
        del(npkt.len)
        del(npkt.chksum)
    elif UDP in pkt:
        npkt = (IP(dst="Public IP")/UDP()/Raw(pkt.payload))
        del(npkt.len)
        del(npkt.chksum)
    send(npkt)
```

[image: Original Pcap File]

Comment: What do the malformed packets look like? If you get rid of the `del`s for a test, does that change anything?

Comment: Malformed packet is not the issue. The real issue is I'm not getting all packets over there. And No, removing del does not make any effect.

Comment: You should specify the `iface` argument to `send`, or else scapy will guess the inerface to send through, and it's often wrong.

Comment: I tried following :- send(packet, iface="eth0").  But still not working. And iface is correct. it's eth0.